# Calling destructor on local dynamic objects

Tags: function, object, dynamic, scope, destructor

Good day,

I was looking to delete the pointers to objects created in a local function. I'm not quite sure how to phrase the question as  this is my first time asking.

Function:

```
Level::loadFile() {
//some code
MazeExit *new_exit;
        new_exit = new MazeExit; 
//some more code
}
```

Destructor:

```
Level::~Level()
{
  delete new_exit;
  new_exit = NULL;
}
```

Now the problem is that the object `new_exit` is now out of scope but I fear the dynamic memory it was allocated may be leaked.

Answer (score 0):

The variable was allocated in the method loadfile, and is only scoped to  that method. since you newed it, when the method returns you did leak memory. if there is no reason to mazeexit exist after load file then don't new it, just declare it. if it truly needs to hang around,  declare it as a member variable so you will be able to delete it in the destructor

Comment: So I will have to initialise it in the constructor?